# TypeError: scorers is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code below gives

> TypeError: scorers is not iterable

```
const sortedScorers = [...scorers].sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number);
```

It seems that this problem only occurs when:

```
existingScorer = true
```

I found this answer, after google search

> error is raised when you try to iterate over an integer value. To solve this error, make sure that you are iterating over an iterable rather than a number.
> But MDN says
> Some built-in constructs—such as the spread syntax—use the same iteration protocol under the hood

Could you please tell me what I can do?

[the gitHub repository](https://github.com/peter-swe/indiv-points)

Thanks in advance
/Peter

edit: my app.js

```js
 const [scorers, setScorers] = useState([
    {id: nanoid(4), number: 9, totPoints: 99},
    {id: nanoid(4), number: 1, totPoints: 11},
    {id: nanoid(4), number: 15, totPoints: 9},
  ]);

  const sortedScorers = [...scorers].sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number);
  const onePointScoredHandler = () => {
    const players = [...scorers];
    const existingScorer = players.find((player) => player.number === +number);

    if (existingScorer) {
      console.log('exist');
      existingScorer.totPoints = setTotPoints((prevState) => prevState + 1);
      setScorers(existingScorer);
    } else {
      console.log('new');
      const newScorer = {
        id: nanoid(4),
        number: +number,
        totPoints: totPoints + 1,
      };
      setScorers([...scorers, newScorer]);
      // setTotPoints(totPoints);
    }
    setNumber('');
    console.log(scorers);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h4>Individual points</h4>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input
        type="number"
        value={number}
        onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={onePointScoredHandler}>Add 1p</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NUMBER</th>
            <th>Total Points</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {sortedScorers
            .sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number)
            .map((player) => (
              <tr key={player.id}>
                <td>{player.id}</td>
                <td>{player.number}</td>
                <td>{player.totPoints}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: What is `scorers`? Please may you show us what it is? (A github link should always be accompanied by a code example in the question itself)

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the code to your question. Nobody is interested in digging around in some github repository ... As for your question: seemingly `scorer` is not an array, so you can't use it in spread syntax ...  and nobody knows what `existingScorer` is or what it has to do with the code shown above ...

Comment: https://github.com/peter-swe/indiv-points/blob/main/src/App.js#L22 change that line to `setScorers([existingScorer])`. I believe `existingScorer` is not an array by itself.

Comment: @derpirscher: sorry for my misstake, promise to do better next time

Comment: @evolutionxbox:sorry for my misstake, I now have the code in my original question

Comment: @aleksxor unfortunately not working :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also change the function logic to achieve the desired result like this way:

```
const onePointScoredHandler = () => {
  const players = [...scorers];
  const pos = players.map((player) => player.number).indexOf(+number);

  if (pos !== -1) {
    console.log("exist");
    players[pos].totPoints = setTotPoints((prevState) => prevState + 1);
    setScorers(players);
  } else {
    console.log("new");
    const newScorer = {
      id: nanoid(4),
      number: +number,
      totPoints: totPoints + 1,
    };
    setScorers([...scorers, newScorer]);
    setTotPoints(totPoints);
  }
  setNumber("");
  console.log(scorers);
};
``
```

Answer (score 0):

As @aleksxor already pointed out the problem is the following line

```
setScorers(existingScorer);
```

where `existingScorer` seems to be a single object. Now with the above line, you are overwriting your existing `scorers` array with a single object. So when you then later try to use the `scorers` array in a spread syntax `[...scorers]` this does not work anymore, because `scorers` is now an object instead of an array.

A simple fix would be to replace the above line with

```
setScorers([existingScorer]);
```

but be aware this will overwrite an existing scorer array, ie, if it already contained some elements, they will be gone from that array. So you probably will need either to append the new element to the existing array or merge the value with an element in the existing array.

```
let s = scorers.find(x => x.number === existingScorer.number);
if (s)
  s.totPoints = existingScorer.totPoints;
else 
  setScorers([...scorers, existingScorer])
```

As long as you don't deepcopy the players, updating the scorer in the `scorers` array may not be needed, because all references are pointing to the same object. So just check if the player is already contained in the `scorers` array and if, not append it.

```
let s = scorers.find(x => x.number === existingScorer.number);
if (!s)
  setScorers([...scorers, existingScorer])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help:-) My apologies for my late reply, but worked many night shifts in a row at PICU.